# Grant AWS CLI permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have a user group `Administrators` with the following policy attached:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My currently logged-in CLI user is part of this group; I've verified by running `aws iam get-user` and comparing the ARN with what I have in the web console.

Somehow there's a lot of CLI commands for which I get denied, e.g.

```sh
$ aws iam list-groups

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListGroups operation: User: arn:aws:iam::675072143536:user/carl is not authorized to perform: iam:ListGroups on resource: arn:aws:iam::675072143536:group/ with an explicit deny
```

How can I perform this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have an attached policy, SCP or Permission Boundary in place that **explicitly denies** that operation. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html .

You may be able to inspect the policy, boundary or SCP in the IAM console or need to ask someone with more permissions / control over your account for more details as to why they are there and how to possibly get permission to go around them. Right now you are not allowed to perform that command.

Comment: I checked and there is no permission boundary set at the user account level, and no SCP set at the organization level.

Answer (score 1):

I was being denied by our MFA policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "NotAction": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "sts:GetSessionToken"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "BoolIfExists": {
            "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an MFA policy, was that just a policy that is attached to your role / user?

Comment: Exactly, a policy intended to enforce multi-factor authentication. I posted it to catch the eye of anyone facing this problem since this MFA policy setup seems to be pretty standard.